# My question is about navigation in react-native and passing parameters by it

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am new to react-native i am trying to make my first app which is a BMI calculator app but i am facing a problem in navigation as I want to use a single touchableopacity button to pass parameters, navigation to another screen, validation of the textInput and also calculation part. I am able to do it using two buttons but its not so good looking so i use the trick of combining function of the two buttons and using on the first button but then also i am unable to do it.

my code:-

```
calc = () => {
var w = this.state.weight;
var h = this.state.height;
var a = this.state.age;
var r = this.state.result;
r = parseInt((w / (h * h)) * 10000);

if(r<18){
  this.setState({answer:'You are Underweight!'})
} else if(r>=18 && r<=25){
  this.setState({answer:'You are Normal!'})
} else if(r>25){
  this.setState({answer:'You are Overweight!'})
} else if (w == '' && h == '' && a=='') {
  alert('Please enter your Weight, Age and Height.');
} else if (w == '' && h == '') {
  alert('Please enter your Weight and Height.');
} else if (a == '' && h=='') {
  alert('Please enter your Age and Height.');
} else if (w == '' && a == '') {
  alert('Please enter your Weight and Age.');
} else if (w==''){
  alert('Please enter your Weight')
} else if(h==''){
  alert('Please enter your Height.')
} else if(a==''){
  alert('Please enter your Age.')
} else {
  this.setState({ result: r });
}
this.props.navigation.navigate('BMI5', { greet: this.state.result, 
ans:this.state.answer, ag:this.state.age, wt:this.state.weight, ht:this.state.height });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the results in a state and then navigating to the new screen using the values previously stored in the state, you could just use the  values directly.

I have optimized the function a little bit as well.

```js
getMissingAttributes = (...args) => {
    const attributes = ['Weight', 'Height', 'Age'];
    const missing = attributes.filter((_, index) => args[index] === '');
    const length = missing.length;
  
    const str = length > 2 ? `${missing.slice(0, length - 1).join(',')} and ${missing[length - 1]}` : length === 2 ? `${missing[0]} and ${missing[1]}`  : `${missing[0]}`;

    return str;
}

calc = () => {
  const w = this.state.weight;
  const h = this.state.height;
  const a = this.state.age;
  
  if (w === '' || h === '' || a === '') {
    alert(`Please enter your ${getMissingAttributes(w, h, a)}`)
    return;
  }

  const r = parseInt((w / (h * h)) * 10000);

  let answer;
    
  if (r < 18) {
    answer = 'You are Underweight!'
  } else if (r >= 18 && r <= 25) {
    answer = 'You are Normal!'
  } else if (r > 25) {
    answer = 'You are Overweight!'
  }
 
  this.setState({ answer: answer, result: r });

  this.props.navigation.navigate('BMI5', {
    greet: r,
    ans: answer,
    ag: a,
    wt: w,
    ht: h,
  });
};
```